# Customizing foreign language event confirmation email

Tags: civievent, message-templates

I have been looking around for a long time, here is what I want to do:
I am using Civi on Wordpress in German language. Now also the confirmation emails for event registrations are in German - great so far.

However, the German texts in the confirmation mails for the "send to a friend" are just way to formal and I would like to customize them. However, I can nowhere find the German texts. I have looked at the message templates, but there is nothing in foreign languages there. Where do I find it?

Thank you for your support in advance
Dennis

Answer (score 1):

For information about how CiviCRM handles languages, see https://lab.civicrm.org/development-team/translations/wikis/home

Text strings in the templates are wrapped in `{ts} ... {/ts}` tags - that is what triggers the translation.

You could customise the German translation, or if your confirmations are only being sent in German, you could customise the confirmation message itself directly in German - see https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/message-templates/